# CSS Grid - Spans overlapping, can't get in-line

Tags: html, css

on my portfolio site, I have boxes which indicate my projects. Where it displays the languages used per project, they seem to overlap entirely and wont adjust to fit all of them in their allocated div while maintaining keeping the skills section and the "visit site" button in line, does anybody know why?

Link to the website in question, feel free to inspect the code:
HTML

```
<article class="project-card">
    <div class="project4img" ></div>
    <div class="project1-header">
        <h5 class="project1">Template 2</h5>
        <h6 class="development">Development start date: 03/06/2018"</h6>
        <p>Started inplimenting CSS Grid for a more easy responsive layout. Also includes vue.js and vanilla js.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bottomSection">
        <div class="skillSection">
            <span class="skill">HTML</span>
            <span class="skill">CSS</span>
            <span class="skill">JAVASCRIPT</span>
            <span class="skill">VUE.JS</span>
        </div>

        <div class="visitSite"><a class="visitProject1" href="https://donnieberry97.github.io/project2/">Visit Site</a></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
.skill {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #92eac0;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Camphor, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    color: #525f7f;
}

.bottomSection {
    padding: 3em 3em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.visitSite {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Add `display: inline-block` to `.skill`

Comment: that _does_ work but it makes the button on the right side mis-aligned and pushes it outside of its div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where flexbox would work wonderfully.

Rather than using grid at all:

```
.bottomSection {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.skillSection {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 50%; // Or whatever width you want here...
}
```

here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ptm1sbc/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Only the direct children of the grid are grid items, so your `span.skill` are not direct children of `div.bottomSection`, So you have no styling on them to align them correctly.

So you can set grid on `div.skillSection` with 4 columns with 1fr each.

```css
.skill {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #92eac0;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Camphor, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif;
  font-size: .85em;
  color: #525f7f;
}

.bottomSection {
  padding: 3em 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.bottomSection>.skillSection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.visitSite {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<article class="project-card">
  <div class="project4img"></div>
  <div class="project1-header">
    <h5 class="project1">Template 2</h5>
    <h6 class="development">Development start date: 03/06/2018"</h6>
    <p>Started inplimenting CSS Grid for a more easy responsive layout. Also includes vue.js and vanilla js.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bottomSection">
    <div class="skillSection">
      <span class="skill">HTML</span>
      <span class="skill">CSS</span>
      <span class="skill">JAVASCRIPT</span>
      <span class="skill">VUE.JS</span>
    </div>

    <div class="visitSite"><a class="visitProject1" href="https://donnieberry97.github.io/project2/">Visit Site</a></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

as side note, consider using `fr` units rather than `%` when defining your columns in CSS grid, talking about this like `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;`